# Nginx Ingress Controller gives - 404 not found

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm using `HA-Proxy` (Independent server) and `Kubernetes v1.25.4` cluster (One master and three workers) bare metal based.

I have deployed `Jenkins` and`Nginx ingress controller` with help of this [Link](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/),

But when i tried to access our jenkins URL `http://jenkins.company.com/jenkins` getting `404 Not Found` error.

**My Jenkins application name space status:-**

```
$ kubectl get all -n jenkins
NAME                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE   
pod/jenkins-75cbc954b6-2wfpt   1/1     Running   2 (13d ago)   70d   

NAME                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/jenkins-svc   ClusterIP   10.96.180.240   <none>        80/TCP    70d

NAME                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE                           
deployment.apps/jenkins   1/1     1            1           70d   

NAME                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE   
replicaset.apps/jenkins-75cbc954b6   1         1         1       70d
```

**Ingress controller status:-**

```
$ kubectl get all -n nginx-ingress
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
pod/nginx-ingress-5xnz4   1/1     Running   2 (13d ago)   70d
pod/nginx-ingress-h2g9p   1/1     Running   3 (13d ago)   70d
pod/nginx-ingress-jgtc9   1/1     Running   2 (13d ago)   70d

NAME                           DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
daemonset.apps/nginx-ingress   3         3         3       3            3           <none>          70d
```

**Ingress pod log:-**

```
$ kubectl logs nginx-ingress-h2g9p -n nginx-ingress
2023/01/09 03:21:33 [notice] 25#25: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
2023/01/09 03:21:33 [notice] 25#25: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 145
2023/01/09 03:21:33 [notice] 25#25: worker process 145 exited with code 0
2023/01/09 03:21:33 [notice] 25#25: worker process 164 exited with code 0
2023/01/09 03:21:33 [notice] 25#25: worker process 178 exited with code 0
2023/01/09 03:21:33 [notice] 25#25: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
```

**Ingress status:-**

```
$ kubectl get ingress jenkins-ingress -n jenkins
NAME              CLASS   HOSTS                 ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
jenkins-ingress   nginx   jenkins.company.com             80      63s
```

```
$ kubectl describe ingress jenkins-ingress -n jenkins
Name:             jenkins-ingress
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        jenkins
Address:
Ingress Class:    nginx
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host             Path  Backends
  ----             ----  --------
  jenkins.company.com
                   /jenkins   jenkins-svc:80 (10.244.2.19:8080)
Annotations:       nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
Events:
  Type    Reason          Age   From                      Message
  ----    ------          ----  ----                      -------
  Normal  AddedOrUpdated  9m4s  nginx-ingress-controller  Configuration for jenkins/jenkins-ingress was added or updated
  Normal  AddedOrUpdated  9m4s  nginx-ingress-controller  Configuration for jenkins/jenkins-ingress was added or updated
  Normal  AddedOrUpdated  9m4s  nginx-ingress-controller  Configuration for jenkins/jenkins-ingress was added or updated
```

Even on Kubernetes cluster master terminal  also `curl` fails with below errors.

```
$ curl -D- http://jenkins.company.com/jenkins -v
*   Trying 160.20.21.6...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to jenkins.company.com (160.20.21.6) port 80 (#0)
> GET /jenkins HTTP/1.1
> Host: jenkins.company.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: nginx/1.23.2
Server: nginx/1.23.2
< Date: Mon, 09 Jan 2023 02:58:06 GMT
Date: Mon, 09 Jan 2023 02:58:06 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 153
Content-Length: 153
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive

<
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.23.2</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host jenkins.company.com left intact
```

Please let me know whats wrong with my configurations side?

Any help will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you do `curl -D- http://jenkins.company.com/jenkins -v` to check it sends the host header?

Comment: I'd say the issue is with the rewrite. Your Jenkins should respond on which exact URL?

Comment: @Dawid Kruk - It should be accessible with following link `http://jenkins.company.com/jenkins`

Comment: Can you check the ingress pods logs? If I remember correctly, when describing the ingress, if it does not have a value for Address, it might be not getting served by the ingress controller

Comment: @AndD - You are right `ingress address is empty`, I have added my `nginx-ingress pod logs` in the question section. I'm running the `Ingress Controller by using a DaemonSet`. uisng this link - `https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/`

Comment: Logs have nothing in particular.. maybe first thing I would try is to delete one of the controller Pods and check the logs when it starts, might log something related to the Ingress resources?

Answer (score 1):

For me its looks, like your request is not reaching to Nginx container itself. so try below mentioned options.

As Nginx-ingress runs as a daemon set, so Nginx container ports 80 and 443 are mapped with the 80 and 443 ports of the host. so you can use http://{node-IP} to connect to Nginx container. You can make use of any node-IP out of 3 nodes. Once the request reaches to Nginx container then it will be routed to the backend container after checking the resource rules that you created. so you can use http//{node-ip}/jenkins to connect to jenkins container.

To test with curl client. may use hostname spoofing.
curl -H "Host: jenkins.company.com" http://{host-ip}/jenkins

Comment: I tried to connect Nginx container using `http://{node-IP}`, But it shows `404 Not Found` on browser. Nginx container Status shows (Running) & Ready shows (1/1). What could the problem?